# acer aspire v3-112p not booting ubuntu from hardware

Tags: boot, acer

I just kill windows and was installing ubuntu 14.04 in a acer v3-112p, the process seemed allright, but when I was trying to boot the machine again from the HHD, I have this 'no bootable device' message. I can run ubuntu from my flash drive but not from the HHD, even though ubuntu is installed on the HHD
I did the procees two times but nothing

I will appreciate any guidelines and suggestions

Comment: Run the Live-Session again and open GParted (can be done from command-line - `gparted`). Try to get a screenshot or take a pic of your screen of the GParted program after it's loaded and selected to your HDD, and put the pic on here.

Answer (score 0):

For the UEFI mode to work properly you need to tell your UEFI to trust the Ubuntu bootloader, see [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/676384/402224).