# Acer Aspire V3 does not recognize my EFI partition

Tags: grub-efi

I just installed Kubuntu on an Acer Aspire V3 netbook with a SSD using GPT and the following partition layout:

- 1 MB unformatted partition with boot_grub flag,
- 200 MB FAT32 partition with boot flag,
- 2GB swap partition,
- 20 GB ext4 partition,
- 90 GB ext4 partition.

The netbook fails to detect my EFI partition. When I disable the secure mode I can access a menu for choosing a boot binary. The menu shows my SSD but no EFI partition on it.

I am only able to boot in legacy mode (using the BIOS partition).
Does anyone has the same netbook booting in EFI mode? What is your partition scheme?

Comment: It sounds like you need to install an EFI boot loader for Linux.  You should disable the BIOS/CSM/legacy support in the firmware, boot a live CD, and run [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) If that doesn't help, post the URL that Boot Repair generates; that will give us necessary details about your configuration.

Comment: I just chatted with the Acer support; they told me to use the Windows 8.1 image to restore my drive :-) Then I told the support guy that I have the Linpus version and he told me that Acer does not support Linux :-( And he didn't know any details about EFI partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the issue, Kubuntu is able to boot with the default UEFI firmware settings (no legacy mode, secure boot enabled). `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` needs to be selected once in the UEFI (press F2 during boot, set a `supervisor password`, then got to `Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing` and pick `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`). The password can be removed afterwards. Here some background information: SHIM (`shimx64.efi`) is a (Microsoft) signed binary used to call GRUB (`grubx64.efi`); GRUB then loads the Linux kernel. By the way when I boot in legacy mode Kubuntu is unable to shut down correctly and crashes every time I try to change the mouse settings; this is solved after switching to UEFI mode.

Comment: Many systems require the work around you just did. But Acer seems to have a process where you set a supervisory password and then drill down to the ubuntu efi boot files and set "trust" http://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi

Comment: Thanks for you remark, I removed the `EFI/boot` folder and selected `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` as trusted for executing and it works too. So I don't need to copy and rename files on the  my EFI partition. I tried that too but for some reason it did not work. I will correct my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for hours to get my Acer laptop to recognise the correct EFI to launch.  The bios didn't have the ability to select a trusted EFI and it while it could successfully boot a windows OS, Linux would failed.  I solved it by copying the Linux EFI into the windows boot folder and renaming shim64x.efi over the windows bootmgr.

Worked like a charm, looks like Acer has hard coded the EFI that will boot.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. If this is confirmed hard coding the path to the bootloader inside the UEFI firmware is ugly.